# Problem in Report Design Layout

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a jasper report with 4 subreports in the detail band of the master report.

If data is available for first subreport, it starts displaying from page 1 with the header of the subreport. When second subreport starts printing data, it prints only header in page 1 and the page breaks and in the page 2, it prints header again n data for that.

I dont want the header of the second subreport to be printed in page1. It should start print in the page 2.

How to solve this..? How could i page break...?

its urgent.Please help.

Thanks in advance,
Prasanna

Answer (score 0):

First start by separating each subreport in its own band. ie. Make a new group for each new subreport.

In the Add/modify group dialog, there is an option called `Print Header on each page`, try to check that

Comment: Thank You.

I did the same and it is fine now.

Regards,
Prasanna